# Finding the sum of all subsets of a given set

Tags: c, algorithm

Suggest an algorithm  for finding the sum of all subsets of a set.

For example, if `k=3` and the subsets are `{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}`
 then  sum of subsets is `{1}+{2}+{3}+{1+2}+{1+3}+{2+3}+{1+2+3}=24`

Comment: I suggest you to try something instead of asking for the direct solution of what looks like a homework

Comment: @Coconop,first of all it is not a homework problem,i m trying to catch an efficient algorithm.

Comment: Ok for "not a homework". Still, the philosophy of SO is "we give you help if you show some research effort".
Anyway, luckily you already get some nice leads for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an input {x<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>n</sub>}, return 2<sup>n-1</sup> (x<sub>1</sub> + … + x<sub>n</sub>), since each term appears in that many sums.

Comment: Maybe your problem is not defined well enough, but I understood that your input is set. For set {3}, answer should be 3 not 4.

Answer (score 1):

Each element appears the same number of times, which happens to be 2<sup>n-1</sup> where n is number of elements. So the answer is: count sum of elements in the set and multiply it by 2<sup>n-1</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Answer:


Total no. of Subsets are 2^n. 

As we don't require an empty set, so total required subsets are 2^n - 1.
Now all we have to do is simply get all possible subsets.

This algorithm will help.

```
    void main()
    {
    //Total no. of elements in set = n;      
    //Let's say the Set be denoted as P[n]
    //declare a global variable sum and initialize to 0.
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
    int r = nCi;
    //here, r = nCi or you can say n combinations i
    //it's good to write an extra function named something like "nCi" to evaluate nCi and call it when required. 
   //define a new two dimensional array of size "r","i", say s[r][i]
   for(int k=0;k<r;k++)
    {
    //define a function to get all combination array for s[r][i] using "i" elements out of total "n"
    //This link will help you with best of code for this particular function
    //<http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/>
    //now for every particular s[r][i], do this
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {

    sum = sum + s[r][j];
    }
    }
        }
        //display total output
        printf("%d",sum);
        }
```