# Subset sum Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I want to use dynamic programming to get the sum of all subsets from a given array.

```
subsets([1,2,3]) = 24
Since the subsets are {1}{2}{3}{1,2}{2,3}{1,3}{1,2,3}
```

I'm trying to calculate subsets([1,2]) which = 6
My implementation below gets 5

```
func subsets(_ arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    var mem = Array(repeating: 0, count: arr.count)
    return subsetsRecursive(arr, 0, &mem)
}

// correct result, but too slow so requires memorization
func subsetsRecursive(_ arr: [Int], _ ptr: Int, _ memo : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    if (ptr > arr.count - 1) {return 0}
    if memo[ptr] != 0 {return memo[ptr]}
    // either take the next number, or don't
    let res = (
        subsetsRecursive(arr, ptr + 1, &memo) + arr[ptr]
            +
        subsetsRecursive(arr, ptr + 1, &memo)
    )
    memo[ptr] = res
    return res
}
```

What needs to be corrected to get the right answers? The approach here is important, it is not homework but is my self-study about dynamic programming (I can find other approaches for this, but want to understand this approach or why it is not possible).

Comment: I know. There's a solution https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25. But I want to get the recursive solution to work...for practice only

Comment: Not a duplicate of a different problem with completely different approaches to the one in this question

Comment: Actually, I've re-read your question, is not a duplicate indeed, apologies.

Comment: No, it's a different question. This question is about a dynamic programming approach to the problem using recursion. Re: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ because if not you  could say it is possible to work out on paper (it is) and then point to that a question with that as the answer.

Comment: A little  bit of research could have led you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29282391/2907715)

Comment: Sorry but the link above doesn’t answer the question at all. Also Martin R already gave a great answer, but thanks for the comment anyway (I’m familiar with that SO question as I did indeed research)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the recursion step does not take into account with *how many* subsets the current element `arr[ptr]` can be combined. For example, `subsets([1,2])` computes the sum of the subsets {1, 2} and {2}, but omits the subset {1}.

A possible fix for the dynamic programming approach would be to remember not only the sum, but also the *count* of all subsets starting at a certain position:

```
func subsets(_ arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    var mem = Array(repeating: (sum: 0, count: 0), count: arr.count)
    return subsetsRecursive(arr, 0, &mem).sum
}

func subsetsRecursive(_ arr: [Int], _ ptr: Int, _ memo : inout [(sum: Int, count: Int)]) -> (sum: Int, count: Int) {
    if (ptr > arr.count - 1) { return (sum: 0, count: 1) }
    if memo[ptr].sum != 0 { return memo[ptr] }
    let res = subsetsRecursive(arr, ptr + 1, &memo)
    memo[ptr] = (2 * res.sum + arr[ptr] * res.count, 2 * res.count)
    return memo[ptr]
}
```

Examples:

```
print(subsets([1, 2])) // 6
print(subsets([1, 2, 3])) // 24
```

This can be simplified further, but hopefully answers your immediate question.

---

An iterative solution would be

```
func subsetsum(_ arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    var count = 1
    for elem in arr {
        sum = 2 * sum + count * elem
        count = 2 * count
    }
    return sum
}
```

which can be written concisely as

```
func subsetsum(_ arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    return arr.reduce((sum: 0, count: 1)) {
        (2 * $0.sum + $0.count * $1, 2 * $0.count )
    }.sum
}
```

---

Alternatively note that each of the n array elements can be in 2<sup>n-1</sup> of the 2<sup>n</sup> subsets:

```
func subsetsum(_ arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    return arr.reduce(0, +) * (1 << (arr.count - 1))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first get all subset elements, join them and use reduce to sum the elements:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection  {
    public var subSets: [SubSequence] {
        return isEmpty ? [SubSequence()] : dropFirst().subSets.lazy.flatMap { [$0, prefix(1) + $0] }
    }
}
```

---

```
let subSets = [1,2,3].subSets // [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

```
let sum = subSets.joined().reduce(0,+)   // 24
```

or

```
let sum = subSets.reduce(0) { $1.reduce($0,+) }
```

Note that extending `RangePlaceableCollection` and returning a `SubSequence` you will be able to use it also with StringProtocol types like `String`s and `Substring`s:

```
let characters = Array("123")
let charactersSubSets = characters.subSets // [[], ["1"], ["2"], ["1", "2"], ["3"], ["1", "3"], ["2", "3"], ["1", "2", "3"]]
let stringSubSets = "123".subSets // ["", "1", "2", "12", "3", "13", "23", "123"]
let substringSubSets = "1234".dropLast().subSets // ["", "1", "2", "12", "3", "13", "23", "123"]
```