# How to find a random combination from given numbers that add up to another number in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

Given a random set of positive integers `A`, find one random combination of int's that add up to `N`.

Ex.

```
A = [4, 2, 10, 8, 13, 1, ...]  
N = 18  
The possibilities are [10, 8], [4, 13, 1], etc.
```

The set `A` can also be any length and can only hold positive integers.

`N` can be any positive integer.

I only need one combination of numbers, not all of them. I would also like to pick randomly so if I'm given the same set, I wouldn't keep getting the same answer every time and I'm looking for the most efficient way I can do this programmatically in Swift.

Comment: How big do you expect `A` to be? Could it be more than 100, for example ?

Comment: When you say "I'm looking for the most efficient way" are you talking time efficiency, space efficiency, or both?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the source data? Will all the elements in A be less than or equal to N? How many elements will there be in A? Will they be truly random, or will there be some pattern or weight to their values?

Comment: This seems like a complex enough problem that proving that a given solution is the "most efficient" solution might be difficult. Leo's solution would certainly work, but I doubt if it is the most efficient solution.

Comment: Will the values in Set A all be unique? (They **are** unique in your sample data. )

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a method to find all possible subsets of your original collection as I posted here [Subset sum Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54586645/2303865). Then you just need to check if any subset sum is equal to n:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection  {
    var subSets: [SubSequence] {
        return isEmpty ? [SubSequence()] : dropFirst().subSets.lazy.flatMap { [$0, prefix(1) + $0] }
    }
}
```

---

```
let a = [4, 2, 10, 8, 13, 1]
let n = 18
let matches = a.subSets.lazy.filter { $0.reduce(0,+) == n }
print("Matches:", Array(matches.map{Array($0)}))  // Matches: [[10, 8], [4, 13, 1]]
```

You can also use a non recursive approach as you can see at another post I have made here [Find all combination of string array in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54602866/2303865). Note that this second approach I did it in a way to do not consider an empty set a subset:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var subSetsNotRecursive : [SubSequence] {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        let count = self.count
        let n = 1 << count - 1
        var subSequences: [SubSequence] = .init(repeating: SubSequence(), count: n-1)
        (0 ..< n).map {
            var counter = 0
            for element in self {
                if $0 & 1 << counter > 0 {
                    subSequences[$0-1].append(element)
                }
                counter += 1
            }
        }
        return subSequences + [self[...]]
    }
}
```

---

```
let matches2 = a.subSetsNotRecursive.lazy.filter { $0.reduce(0,+) == n }
print("Matches2:", Array(matches2.map{Array($0)}))  // Matches2: [[10, 8], [4, 13, 1]]
```

Or expanding it further. If you are only interested on those sets that summed are equal to a certain value, you can check every time you finish creating your set if the sum of the elements that where appended are equal to the value you want:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: BinaryInteger {
    func subSetsThatSummedAre(equalTo value: Element) -> [SubSequence] {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        let count = self.count
        let n = 1 << count - 1
        var subSets: [SubSequence] = []
        (0 ..< n).map {
            var counter = 0
            var sum: Element = 0
            var subSequence = SubSequence()
            for element in self {
                if $0 & 1 << counter > 0 {
                    subSequence.append(element)
                    sum += element
                }
                counter += 1
            }
            if sum == value {
                subSets.append(subSequence)
            }
        }
        if reduce(0, +) == value {
            subSets.append(self[...])
        }
        return subSets
    }
}
```

---

```
let matches4 = a.subSetsThatSummedAre(equalTo: n)
print("Matches4:", Array(matches4.map{Array($0)}))  // Matches4: [[10, 8], [4, 13, 1]]
```

Comment: That would certainly work but I doubt if it's the "most efficient" solution the OP is asking for. Do you know the time complexity of your `Subset sum` function?

Comment: Note that I added the array maping only for displaying purpose. That map it is not needed.

Comment: @DuncanC now you have 3 completely different approaches. You can check which one is faster.

Comment: Don't both the recursive and non-recursive "compute all subsets" functions have at least `O(n²)` time complexity? That's how it looks to me at a glance. Thus I doubt if this is the "most efficient" solution the OP asked for.

Comment: How would it be possible do it without combining them? OP didn’t even have a solution for that. I don’t think OP requirement can be so complex that any of those solutions wouldn’t suffice.

Comment: At a glance, one optimization would be to remove all values > N from the set before you begin. Then say that any value = N is a single-element solution, and remove it from the set.

Comment: @DuncanC create a GitHub and post the link. Then do the benchmark in a real project before we can even start a discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188559/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: @Duncan don't you mean 2**n?

Comment: `1 << n` is the same as `pow(2,n)`

Comment: Leo: i know that. I'm asking @Duncan about his statement that your algorithms are "at least O(n²)", which seems to me to be an underestimate.

Comment: @LeoDabus can you plase provide this example with array of dictionary?